# joukowski transform of a line

Tags: complex-analysis

Given $D=\{r(\sin(\alpha)+i\cos(\alpha))\mid r>0\}= \{e^{x+ i y} \mid x\in \mathbb{R} \}$ (for fixed a $y$ and $\alpha$) i need to find $f(D)$ where $f$ is the the [joukowski transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joukowsky_transform): $$f(z)=\frac{1}{2}(z+\frac{1}{z})$$

After playing around with it i got to ($y=\theta$) $$\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{2}\left(e^{x}-e^{-x}\right)+i\frac{\cos\left(\theta\right)}{2}\left(e^{x}+e^{-x}\right)$$

I am afraid i got somewhat lost, Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

turns out that all i needed was the following:

$$\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{2}\left(e^{x}-e^{-x}\right)+i\frac{\cos\left(\theta\right)}{2}\left(e^{x}+e^{-x}\right)$$

if we take $u=\frac{\sin\left(\theta\right)}{2}\left(e^{x}-e^{-x}\right)$ and $v=\frac{\cos\left(\theta\right)}{2}\left(e^{x}+e^{-x}\right)$ then i get that:
$$ \frac{v^2}{sin^2(y)} - \frac{u^2}{cos^2(y)}=1$$
Which means i get a hyperbola!